# Is there a word that describes words like 'freeware', 'shareware'?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I'm looking for a word that describes the way software is released. It could be freeware, shareware, donationware, commercial, etc.

Comment: Licence. (general reference...)

Comment: License is with an 's'

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't know that.

Comment: Demn dem Yankees!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all "License Terms" or "License Types". Sometimes I see these terms used to indicate "Release Type", maybe when the same piece of software has multiple versions, where the Freeware version has fewer features and no support when compared to the Commercial version.